# Using variables in Firebase path with vanilla JS when updating multiple keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to update multiple paths at the same time with my Firebase database, but each path requires variables to define:

```
const update_referral_path = "referrals/" + referral_code.trim() + "/" + current_user_id
const new_referral_path = "profile/" + current_user_id + "/user_dict/profile/referral_code"
```

I'm using this code to update it, but Firebase as expected updates the database with the literal string "update_referral_path" and "new_referral_path."

```
    admin.database().ref().update({
        update_referral_path: current_time,
        new_referral_path: generated_referral_code
    }, error => {
        if (error) {
            console.log("updateReferral failed")
            return false
        } else {
            console.log("updateReferral succeeded")
            return true
        }
    })
```

I've seen ways to use variables in Angular with backticks and double brackets, but I'm unsure how I can do this in vanilla JS and can't find any examples of people doing so? What are my options?

Answer (score 1):

To use the value of the variable in a key, use `[]` notation:

```
admin.database().ref().update({
    [update_referral_path]: current_time,
    [new_referral_path]: generated_referral_code
}, error => {
    ...
```

---

You can also build a literal JSON object outside of the `update` call:

```
let updates = {};
updates[update_referral_path] = current_time;
updates[new_referral_path = generated_referral_code;
admin.database().ref().update(updates);
```